# AngularJS выбрать radiobutton программно (через функцию)

Tags: angularjs

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="approvedRevisions" ng-change="load(0)">
    Opt1
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" value ng-model="approvedRevisions" ng-change="load(1)">
    Opt2
</label>
<input type="button" value="Change radio" ng-click="changeRadio()">
```

Контроллер:

```
$scope.load = function (flag) {
    if (flag) {
        alert('2');
    } else {
        alert('1');
    }
};
$scope.changeRadio = function () {

        Как правильно выбрать радио  Opt1 ?

};
```

При вызове определенной функции(в данном случае при нажатии кнопки), радиобатон должен переключатся на Opt1. Как это правильно делать?
[Вот пример.](http://plnkr.co/edit/OKZtnd34mkLWdjjU9Dea?p=preview)

Comment: что именно должно происходить по клику на кнопке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте двухстороннее связывание в Angular - просто присвойте нужное значение модели `$scope.approvedRevisions`

```
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="approvedRevisions" value="opt1">
        Opt1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="approvedRevisions" value="opt2">
        Opt2
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Change radio" ng-click="changeRadio()">
</body>
```

```
$scope.changeRadio = function () {
    if ($scope.approvedRevisions === 'opt1') {
        $scope.approvedRevisions = 'opt2';
    } else {
        $scope.approvedRevisions = 'opt1';
    }
};
```

[Рабочий пример на Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k24HotzEBRgDJAZyRhO3?p=preview)